# AGI script executes without error , but no results generated

Tags: asterisk, agi

I am trying to run a shell script using asterisk AGI. I have used the tutorial mentioned here 
http://www.shiffman.net/p5/asterisk/

My extensions.conf is as follows

```
[default]
include => clicall

[clicall]
exten => _X,1,Goto(s,1);
exten => _X.,1,Goto(s,1);
exten => s,1,Answer();
exten => s,n,EAGI(runEAGI.sh);
```

The script I am trying to run  (runEAGI.sh) is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
java /home/sphata001/Downloads/EAGI/JEAGIClient $$
```

The permissions have been set as 755 and the script is placed in `/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/`. The java file(JEAGIClient) has been compiled beforehand as well . When executing the script manually it runs fine and connects to the server. 
But when making a call from SIP client the script executes according to asterisk console but no results are to seen.
I get the following output in the console

```
 == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [888@default:1] Goto("SIP/1001-00000027", "s,1") in new stack
    -- Goto (default,s,1)
    -- Executing [s@default:1] Answer("SIP/1001-00000027", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@default:2] EAGI("SIP/1001-00000027", "runEAGI.sh") in new stack
    -- Launched AGI Script /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/runEAGI.sh
    -- <SIP/1001-00000027>AGI Script runEAGI.sh completed, returning 0
    -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/1001-00000027' status is 'UNKNOWN'
```

Any solutions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likly - you need specify full path to java.

Hint: For debugging asterisk AGI simple solution is stop asterisk and start it attached to console, that way you will see all script errors.

```
asterisk -rx "core stop now"
asterisk -vvvvgc
```

Also can be usfull enable AGI debugging in asterisk console:

```
agi set debug on
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding the complete java path did help. It's working like a charm now. Thanks a lot once again.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the script and any resources it requires is owned by the Asterisk user, and that SELinux is not preventing the script from running correctly